# datagrid with fixed header and scrollbars

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

Is possible set fixed header and scrollbar in a datagrid?

How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have at this codeproject entry: [Fixed Header in ASP.NET DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/DataGridFixedHeader.aspx)

Comment: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
has problems with firefox and chrome

Comment: Neither did the code given at that CodeProject site didn't work for me in Firefox.  I'm still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this for awhile and gave up on making the CSS work on all browsers.  A simple albeit not elegant way to accomplish this is to just have two distinct tables whose column widths match up.  The first table holds the headers and the second holds the content and is scrollable.

I used jQuery to make all the column widths match up.

For a complete description, see this post:  [Scrollable DataGrid table with Fixed Header with jQuery](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/scrollable-datagrid-table-with-fixed-header-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I placed a second datagrid above the original, I sized all the columns in both datagrids equally.  In the datagrid that shows the data, I set the header to not show.  In the code behind I bound the top datagrid to an empty data table and set the bound fields to show the header when empty.

```html
<div style="padding-bottom:2px">
<asp:GridView id="RoleListHeader" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" showheaderwhenempty="True" showheader="true" height="20px" width="350px" selectedrowstyle-height="20px" rowstyle-height="20px" headerstyle-height="10px" forecolor="#ff333333" backcolor="White">
 <columns>
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="23">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox></asp:CheckBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="SystemDesc" HeaderText="Role Description" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="174"></asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="EndDate" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="153"></asp:BoundField>
 </columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
<div style="max-height:300px;overflow:auto">
<asp:GridView id="RoleList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" showheaderwhenempty="True" showheader="false" height="0px" width="350px" selectedrowstyle-height="20px" rowstyle-height="20px" headerstyle-height="10px" forecolor="#ff333333" backcolor="White" rowstyle-horizontalalign="Center" rowstyle-borderstyle="Solid" rowstyle-bordercolor="#ff404040">
 <columns>
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="23">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="GVChkBox_CheckChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:CheckBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

  <asp:BoundField DataField="SystemDesc" HeaderText="Role Description" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="174"></asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="EndDate" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="153"></asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ADHSystemId" ShowHeader="false"></asp:BoundField>
 </columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```